# Appropriate design for mutlithreaded asynchronous server app?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous

I have a three layer application with your basic client layer, middle layer, and database layer. The middle layer is intended to take requests for work and data from the client, process it, and then store it in the database.

There are a few key points here:

1. First, requests for work from the client layer should be asynchronous
   so the client isn't waiting around for the work to be finished.
2. Second, multiple clients need to be able to access the middle layer
   at the same time. If only one connection at a time was possible, that
   could be ok if the clients can be forced to wait.
3. Third, the middle layer's work needs to be parallelized to take advantage of the multi-core server it will be running on.
4. Finally, performance is generally important here. I don't have
   specific benchmarks, but it's likely I'll be crunching a lot of
   data, so making sure the design facilitates reasonable performance
   is import.

Given all of this, I'm having trouble designing the middle layer. For one thing, what's the best way for the client and the middle layer to connect? I had originally conceived using TCP to connect the two by using a middle layer with one main thread for handling connections and taking the data from clients and then spinning off children thread to do the actual work so the clients wouldn't have to wait.

However, would WCF be a better choice? If I do, how do I make that work asynchronously? Also, it seems like I would be using the parallel for each loop in each service call that does the work - is that correct? Or is there a better approach here that I'm not seeing?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: please don't **[cross-post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info "'Cross-posting is frowned upon...'")**: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44556302/appropriate-design-for-mutlithreaded-asynchronous-server-app "Cross-posting is frowned upon as it leads to fragmented answers splattered all over the network..."

Comment: I woudl say **workflow** each client request don't launch the job but save a new workflow instance that an engine handle for you.

Comment: gnat: yes, thank you, I've already deleted that post.
Walfrat: Are you suggesting using Windows Workflow Foundation? I'm not particularly familiar with it but I'm starting my research there now.

Answer (score 0):

For reference, I've figured out the answer to my problem. I used WCF for the middle layer along with System.Threading's parallel processing library. I also used TCP to handle the connection, although that approach requires either IIS 7.0 or later or a custom service host to host the WCF middle layer.

Hopefully that provides someone in the future with guidance they may need that I had to figure out on my own.